# How do I delete value from one textfield after the other as long as x button on keyboard is pressed

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have 4 textfields that accept 1 digit each for pin code. Each time I type a number it automatically moves to another textfield for the 2nd digit until it reaches last textfield for the 4th digit. This works fine. However, when I click on the delete (x) button on the number pad, to change the numbers, it won't delete the numbers unless I'm on the 4th textfield only then it moves and delete the 3rd then 2nd then 1st textfields as long as the delete (x) button is pressed.

here's the code

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    // On inputing value to textfield

    if ((textField.text?.count)! < 1  && string.count > 0){
        if(textField == pinOne){
            pinTwo.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        if(textField == pinTwo){
            pinThree.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        if(textField == pinThree){
            pinFour.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        textField.text = string
        if let actualText = textField.text {
            let pinEntered: Character = Character(actualText)
            concatString += String(pinEntered)

            if concatString.count == 4 {
                checkPin()
            }
        }

        return false

    } else if ((textField.text?.count)! >= 1  && string.count == 0){


      // On Deleting value from Textfield

        if(textField == pinTwo){
            pinOne.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        if(textField == pinThree){
            pinTwo.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        if(textField == pinFour) {
            pinThree.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        textField.text = ""
        return false

    }

}
```

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: i have used https://github.com/varunpm1/VPMOTPView library to implement the same functionaliy. It has a variety of options..just in case if you want to use it.

Comment: @WasimMalek, Thanks. I'll try this out.

Comment: When you are in first three pin fields, what happens if you step over this method? And I guess try move your `becomeFirstResponder` after clearing the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this action of close button:-
    @IBAction func CloseAction(_ sender: Any) {

```
    if !(self.pinFour.text?.isEmpty)! || self.tagValue == 4 {

        self.pinFour.text = ""
        self.pinThree.becomeFirstResponder()

    }else if !(self.pinThree.text?.isEmpty)! || self.tagValue == 3{


        self.pinThree.text = ""
        self.pinTwo.becomeFirstResponder()
    }else if !(self.pinTwo.text?.isEmpty)! || self.tagValue == 2{


        self.pinTwo.text = ""
        self.pinOne.becomeFirstResponder()
    }else if !(self.pinOne.text?.isEmpty)! || self.tagValue == 1{


        self.pinOne.text = ""

    }
    self.tagValue -= 1
}
```